# How to search entire table for a phrase in Powerquery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How to check in powerquery, if an entire table contains the search value in any column or any row. Say we have a table:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+
|  column1   |  column2  | column3 |
+------------+-----------+---------+
| apple      | banana    | cherry  |
| damson     | entawak   | fig     |
| watermelon | wolfberry | plum    |
+------------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to find in which column and a row there is `wolfberry`? It is c=2 and r=3. I would like to use the coordinates for further data processing.

Here is a code of sample table for your convenience:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSiwoyElV0lFKSswDQiAjOSO1qKhSKVYnWiklMbc4Pw8olppXkliemH1oAZCdlpkOlixPLEktyk3NASsoz89JSwLr01EqyCnNVYqNBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use following technique:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSiwoyElV0lFKSswDQiAjOSO1qKhSKVYnWiklMbc4Pw8olppXkliemH1oAZCdlpkOlixPLEktyk3NASsoz89JSwLr01EqyCnNVYqNBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t, Column3 = _t]),
    func = (word) =>
            [r = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "r", 1, 1),
             c = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Transpose(Source), "c", 1, 1),
             coordinates = [r = Table.FindText(r, word)[r]{0}, c = Table.FindText(c, word)[c]{0}]
            ][coordinates],
    search = func("wolfberry")
in
    search
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. The solution is achieved by a mixture of `Table.FindText` and `Index`.